# I need MySQL table to get PHP result group by month wise with separate table?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

- **|id|name |month**   |
  =================== |1 |john |January | |2 |geo  |June    | |3 |roy  |june    | |4 |bon  |June    | |5 |ron  |January | |6 |jeny |March
  | |7 |bily |March   | |8 |frnk |May     | |9 |joe  |June    |

  i need to result as a monthly tables and print same month in one
  table.

  January |id|name |month   |
  =================== |1 |john |January | |5 |ron  |January |

  ============================

  March

  |id|name |month   |
  =================== |6 |jeny |March   | |7 |bily |March   |

  ============================

  May

  |id|name |month   |
  ===================== |8 |frnk |May     |
  ============================ June

  |id|name |month   |
  ======================== |2 |geo  |June    | |3 |roy  |june    | |4 |bon  |June    |

  ===========================

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not fetch multiple results in a single query. 
If you need result of single month then use

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE month='january'
```

If you need all month group wise in a single table use

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE GROUP BY month
```

Comment: Thanks. But its print to separate tables.i need print like April data in same table and june date print separate table

Comment: Ok then use loop. 
First create a month array
$month = array('january', feb, march....);
foreach($month as $key => $value){
     //Apply your query here
     //Select * from table where month=$value
//Append data to an array
array_push($result, $data)
}
You ll have a set of result array..